# after upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 gnome on Wayland not working, shortcuts in unity not working anymore

Tags: nvidia, gnome, shortcut-keys, 17.10, wayland

OK, I did the upgrade to 17.10 and regretted it shortly thereafter:
- gnome on wayland is not possible. I use the nvidia GTX 1050 graphics card, a rather popular card I would think, but no: 17.10 won't work with it. The tweaks I googled are for more adventurous people than me.
- so I use UNITY at login. Important shortcuts don't work anymore: CTRL ALT T does not give me the terminal. SHFT PrtScn does not work, etc.

Can somebody explain what is going on?

171102: additional info on shortcuts: 
I can take a screenshot from the terminal, but with following message:

alaindef@alan9:~$ gnome-screenshot -a
** Message: Unable to select area using GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.

with this method from terminal, I can take a screenshot, but with the shortcut SHFT-PrtScn, it does not work. Also most other shortcuts do not work anymore.

171107: I gave up trying to work with Unity because my shortcuts are gone, and I gave up looking for wayland because NVIDIA GTX 1050 will probably not like it.
So I choose the "gnome on xorg" desktop. Although I miss some good stuff of Unity, it gives me back the shortcuts and it offers interesting features, like the workspaces.

Comment: What's going on is the deafult session (wayland) still doesn't support proprietary graphics drivers. With Nvidia (and Nvidia drivers) you have to use Xorg instead.

Comment: Does 17.10 work if you run it live ? Debugging failed upgrades is a pain and takes longer than a fresh install. If Wayland does not work with the open source nvidia drivers, consider filing a bug report.

Comment: @user535733: processor: i5x4,  Graphics GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2.  monitors: DELL P2416D (2560x1440) and Samsung Syncmaster (1920x1200)

Comment: @MichaelBay: I check "Unity" in the login, it is the only thing that works. NVIDIA is giving me a hard time I'm afraid. in 17.04 I had to revert the ubuntu default drivers back to 375. With the new 17.10 I have apparently NVIDIA Driver Version 384.90.  Maybe I have to revert these drivers also to 375? I am not keen on experimenting in the dark though.

Comment: @Panther: The upgrade itself went fine. the problem is that I can only run Unity on it, probably due to the NVIDIA drivers. I could live with that, but why are my shortcuts to open a terminal (CTRL ALT T) and to take a screenshot (SHFT PrtScn) gone?

Comment: You are not the only one who have problems after upgrading to 17.10. *Several things might fail*. See for example this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/973825/an-upgrade-from-artful-to-zetsy-is-no-not-supported-trying-to-upgrade-from/973859#973859