# An upgrade from 'artful' to 'zesty' is not supported. Trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, 17.10

I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04 with a slight problem. I was not able to do anything when I got to the login screen. All I saw was the login-screen, no cursor, and the text cursor blinked a few times and stopped. I read on a forum about someone who had a similar problem, and followed their advice to upgrade right away to 17.10 from 17.04 without trying to fix the login problem.

So I entered recovery mode and started upgrading to 17.10. This was not completely pain free either. I had to set up an ethernet interface, run dhcp and even change the dns-server manually. But after this it started downloading.

Halfway through it gets to around "setting up base files" and just sits there for an hour. I figured it froze and restarted.

Now when I enter recovery mode and run dpkg I get the message

```
An upgrade from 'artful' to 'zesty' is no not supported with this tool
```

but that's not what I'm trying to do. `apt-get update` only wants to remove some files and `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get install -f` both get stuck on `setting up base files (9.6ubuntu102)`.

I don't remember exactly what I did but I was also able to see what files where not installed, and there were a lot of files from the unity package. Doesn't 17.10 use GNOME instead?

Comment: You can not do that (skip releases) See https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading . You are best off with a fresh install at this point.

Answer (score 1):

### Fresh installation often easiest and fastest

It is often easiest and fastest to make a fresh installation instead of upgrading from a previous version. This is 'particularly true', when you would have to upgrade via several steps (not from the previous version, but from a version further back).

- Backup your personal files.
- Install a fresh system.
- Install the additional program packages that you remember (that you need).
- Copy back your personal files from the backup. It helps (but is not necessary) to use a separate **`data`** partition for your personal data.
- Later on, when you need another program package, install it. This way you will get rid of old program packages, that you will not use.

Comment: I think I need to suck it up and go for a fresh install

Comment: I think it will be the best way. Good luck :-)